# Problems with 1386 architecture

Tags: 16.04

So I guess somewhere along the line I accidentally typed 1386 instead of i386 when working with repositories (I think it was when downloading wine).

When I run `sudo apt-get update`, it shows:

```
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i1386/Packages' as repository 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i1386'
```

I've tried removing all the wine ppa and also run:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture 1386
```

and I got:

```
dpkg: warning: cannot remove non-foreign architecture '1386'
Odd number of elements in hash assignment at /usr/share/pkg-config-dpkghook line 30.
```

Comment: It is not `1386`, it is `i386`. See the difference?

Comment: Close voters! How is this off-topic?

Answer (score 4):

The messages you get indicate that the architecture you added was `'i1386'`, not 1386. Try the following:

```
sudo dpkg --remove-architecture i1386
```